# Regex in Perl not matching a Unicode String

Tags: perl, unicode

I'm trying to match a Unicode string using Perl regex. The string seems to arrive at my module unscathed with proper encoding if I output it to STDOUT: "Asuncion, Distrito Capital de Paraguay, Región Oriental, Paraguay."

However, it won't match in Regex. Oddly, if I copy the output of the script into a variable and evaluate that, that *does* match in the same Regex:

```
use v5.12;
use utf8;

my $placeString = $main::FORM{'placeString'}; # Coming from a different module.
say STDOUT $placeString;

utf8::upgrade($placeString); # Using this or removing this seems to make no difference.

# If I manually copy the output of STDOUT (above) in BASH and set the string, it works:
$placeString2 = "Asuncion, Distrito Capital de Paraguay, Región Oriental, Paraguay"; 

if ($placeString =~ /^([\w\s\,\.\-\']+)$/) {
    # This is evaluated as false.
    say STDERR "Accepted placename.";
}


if ($placeString2 =~ /^([\w\s\,\.\-\']+)$/) {
    # This is evaluated as true.
    say STDERR "Accepted placename.";
}
```

Comment: Is it the diacritic mark above the "o" that is the problem? If you reduce the string to only that letter do you still get the problem?

Comment: Yes. If everything is ASCII, such as it would be if I use an unaccented “o,” it works just fine.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce with [this](https://pastebin.com/NFN9dTkh) script, the output from the script is [here](https://pastebin.com/7TNys92K)

Comment: Hmm... interesting. In that `printf` comparison, they do appear differently in my actual code even though they display to STDOUT identically: 1: 52.65.67.69.C3.B3.6E
2: 52.65.67.69.F3.6E

Comment: *"C3.B3"* : That is the UTF8 encoding of "ó". [Here](https://pastebin.com/pek31HKY) is an example, which gives [this](https://pastebin.com/tGkbeRAW) output

Comment: So, if that's the correct encoding, why does it show up as F3 in my embedded string/your sample code? Do I need to do something more to the string that has C3.B3 instead? Perhaps more to the point, why isn't the regex recognizing it, do you think? Thanks for your help!

Comment: "*why does it show up as F3"* : That is the Unicode code point value. The utf-8 encoding of unicode 0xF3 is 0xC3 0xB3. You need to decode the value from the other module first. Try `Encode::decode_utf8()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it won't match in Regex.

From the comments it becomes clear that the value is a UTF-8 encoded string. You need to decode the value before doing the match:

```
use Encode qw(decode_utf8);
$placeString = decode_utf8($placeString);
```

Answer (score 3):

`$placeString2` is a string of decoded text. You could also call this a string of Unicode Code Points, because that's what each of its character are.

```
52.65.67.69.F3.6E      Unicode Code Points for "Región".
```

Each of these UCP would fit in a byte, that's not always going to be the case.

```
49.2665.53.4F          Unicode Code Points for "I♥SO".
```

---

`$placeString` is a string of encoded text. Each of its character is a byte.

```
52.65.67.69.C3.B3.6E   "Región" encoded using UTF-8.
```

```
49.E2.99.A5.53.4F      "I♥SO" encoded using UTF-8.
```

---

Decode inputs, encode outputs.

`\w` and `\s` expect to match Unicode Code Points. But as we've established, the value of `$::FORM{placeString}` is the encoding of these Code Points. You will need to decode it.

```perl
my $placeString = $::FORM{placeString};
utf8::decode($placeString)
   or warn(...);
```

or

```perl
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

my $placeString = decode_utf8($::FORM{placeString});
```

If the string came from a file handle, it would probably be better to add an decoding layer to the handle instead.

Comment: Thanks, ikegami. It is actually coming from the processing of POST and GET via CGI/FastCGI. The program used the classic RegEx to decode the uri_encoding, but never ran into any problems (I saw) stopping at that point without further unicode processing once I enabled `use utf8`. Clearly, I hadn't tried to pattern match utf8 data, though.  Is there any reason not to run `decode_utf8` on every value coming in? I thought I might try to evaluate if there is a performance hit from such.

Comment: `use utf8;` simply tells Perl the source is encoded using UTF-8. It expects the source to be encoded using ASCII otherwise. Use or don't use that according to the encoding of the source.

Comment: Re "*Is there any reason not to run decode_utf8 on every value coming in?*", Generally speaking, you want to decode inputs and encode outputs. It rarely makes sense to work with encoded text, especially if more than one different encodings are accepted. But it could be that you want to leave something as bytes. Or it could be that it's not UTF-8. In those cases, you would not use decode_utf8 or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content="Some Text With UTF8 letters"

# convert to UCS:
$content2=$content; utf8::decode($content2);

# apply regex:
$content2=~s/\W//g; 

# convert from UCS:
$content=$content2; utf8::encode($content);
```